# Sending base64 string in Ajax request from Javascript application gives me 413 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, reactjs, react-native

Working on React-native application and trying to send base64 string in Ajax. It works for some small images, but gives error of 413 (payload is too big, size exceeds) for some large images.
But surprisingly when I'm hitting same request from Postman, it accepts any size of image, means there's no restriction from backend or database side.

How can I allow this from front-end side (react-native application) too?

Comment: Could post your code the of Ajax function ?

Comment: Here's it:

```apiConfig.updateInfo(userId, JSON.stringify(infoChangeData), JSON.stringify(ReqLocationChangeData), userImage).then(reqDetails => {
    return apiUtil.apiFetch(reqDetails.url, {
       method: reqDetails.method,
          headers: reqDetails.headers,
          body: reqDetails.body
       })
})
.then((res) => {
   if (res["status"] == 'OK') {
      dispatch({ 
         type: UPDATING_USER_INFO_DONE, 
            payload: {infoChangeData, locationChangeData, userImage}
         });
    }
})
 .catch((err) => {
    apiUtil.restartApp(this.props.navigation);
})```